# Does leadtools controls supports mvc 4 razor views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, leadtools-sdk

Does `leadtools` controls supports `mvc4 razor views`? I have facing many issues regarding integration of leadtools `html5` controls in `mvc4` projects.

Answer (score 1):

Although the toolkit does not contain demos built with MVC, there aren't any known problems using LEADTOOLS with such projects.
The first thing to verify is whether the basic demos shipped with the toolkit are working properly when hosted locally on the same PC where the toolkit is installed.
If you have the latest toolkit, the demos are installed in this folder:
[LEADTOOLS 19]\Examples\JS\

Note that you need to configure LEADTOOLS REST services on your machine before running these  HTML5 demos. You can do this using the LEADTOOLS Services Host Manager which ships with the SDK. You can find it in the following folder:
[LEADTOOLS 19]\Bin\Dotnet4[platform]\LeadtoolsServicesHostManager_Original.exe
where [platform] is either x64 or Win32.